# Finite Difference Method for Poisson's Equation

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, numerical-calculus

I'm writing a Python program to solve Poisson's equation

$$ \nabla^2 u = f  \quad \mathrm{on} \quad \Omega $$
with
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0 \quad \mathrm{on} \quad \partial \Omega. $$

Here, I use a five-point stencil to discretize the Laplace operator and for each node in the computational domain, the resulting equation is

$$ \frac{1}{\delta x^2}(u_{i-1,j} + u_{i+1,j} - 2u_{i,j}) + \frac{1}{\delta y^2}(u_{i,j-1} + u_{i,j+1} - 2u_{i,j}) = f_{i,j}. $$

If there are $M$ cells in the $x$-direction and $N$-cells in the $y$-direction in the computational domain, I write my program so that each row of the corresponding matrix corresponds $only$ to the interior points of the grid - that is to say, $x(2:M-1)\times y(2:M-1)$.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

# Limits in x
a = 0
b = 2

# Limits in y
c = 0
d = 1

# Computational cells in x-direction
M = 4

# Cells in y-direction
N=4
dx = (b - a)/M
dy=(d - c)/N
x=np.arange(a,2.0001,dx)
y=np.arange(c,1.0001,dy)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Right-hand side function
def f(x,y):
    return np.cos(np.pi*x)*((12*y**2)-(12*y)+2-((np.pi**2)*(y**2)*(1-y)**2))

# Matrix only has entries for the (M-1)*(N-1) interior grid points 
# of the discretized computational domain
N2=(M-1)*(N-1)
A=np.zeros((N2,N2))

for j in range(N-1): 
    for i in range(M-1):
        modInd = int((j)*(M-1)) + i 
        # Handles corner nodes 
        if j == 0 and i == 0:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -(1/dx**2 + 1/dy**2)
        elif i == M-2 and j == 0:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -1/dx**2 - 1/dy**2
        elif i == 0 and j == N-2:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -1/dx**2 - 1/dy**2
        elif i == M - 2 and j == N-2:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -1/dx**2 - 1/dy**2 
            
        # Handles boundary nodes
        elif j == 0 and 0 < i < M -2:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -(2/dx**2 + 1/dy**2)
        elif j == N-2 and 0 < i < M - 2:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -(2/dx**2 + 1/dy**2)
        elif i == 0 and 0 < j < N - 2:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -(1/dx**2 + 2/dy**2)
        elif i == M-2 and 0 < j < N-2:
            A[modInd,modInd] = -(1/dx**2 + 2/dy**2)  
            
        # Interior nodes
        else:
            A[modInd][modInd] = -2*(1/dx**2 + 1/dy**2)
        
        #Handles off-diagonal matrix entries from
        #points left and right of node in 5-pt stencil
        if i >= 0 and i < M-2:
             A[modInd+1][modInd] = 1/dx**2  
        if i > 0 and i <= M-2:
             A[modInd-1][modInd] = 1/dx**2
            
        #Handles entries in identity sub-matrices from
        #points north and south of node in 5-pt stencil
        if j > 0 and j <=N-2:
                A[modInd][modInd - (M-1)] = 1/dy**2
        if j >=0 and j < N - 2:
                A[modInd][modInd + (M-1)] = 1/dy**2
 
r=np.zeros(N2)  
     
# Right-hand side vector r     
for i in range (0,M-1):
    for j in range (0,N-1):           
        r[i+(N-1)*j]=f(x[i+1],y[j+1])
        print(x[i+1],y[i+1])

r[0] = 0
A[0,:] = 0
A[0,0] = 1
        
U = np.linalg.solve(A,r)
U = U.reshape(N-1,N-1)

Xint = X[1:N,1:N]
Yint = Y[1:N,1:N]
[fig, ax] = plt.subplots()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(Xint,Yint,U)
```

The following should produce an approximation the is second order accurate, but it doesn't. Regardless of how fine I make the grid, my numerical solution is always downshifted by some amount. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python. However, it seems to me according to your code that you are going only once through your spatial loops, right? You need a third loop to solve your problem or use the inverse matrix method for the elliptic PDE. Here's a YT clip that explains why you need a third loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWCNVF9oMkw

Comment: In my case the third loop isn't necessary.

Comment: Your problem formulation is invariant under additions of constants. So if you do not explicitly fix the value at one (any one) point, it will be fixed for you with unexpected values. Alternatively the constant is fixed by prescribing the value of the integral over the solution or similar conditions.